# Merge hash with array values to one array

Tags: ruby, merge

How to merge hash with array values to one array:

```
h = {
    one: ["one1", "one2"],
    two: ["two1", "two2"]
}
```

after merge should be:

```
["one1","one2","two1","two2"]
```

Comment: is the order important? or is `["two1", "two2", "one1", "two2"]` acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h.values.flatten
# => ["one1", "one2", "two1", "two2"]
```

You can do the same for the keys, of course. The only reason you need `flatten` here is because the values are themselves arrays, so `h.values` alone will return `[["one1", "one2"], ["two1", "two2"]]`.

Also, just as an FYI, `merge` [means something different (and pretty useful) in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

If you want to make sure it flattens only one level (per @tokland's comment), you can provide an optional argument to `flatten` such as with `flatten(1)`.

Comment: nit-pick: `flatten(1)` is more precise.

Comment: @tokland Depends on the situation, as it's not currently clear that the OP wants to flatten one level. I'll add a note, though.

Comment: Yeah. My point is that `flatten` is overused. A lots of times we only need to flatten one level and still we call a recursive flat. Maybe the OP has nested arrays, but in this case he would (should've) put it in the example. Just a detail, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

```
h.flat_map &:last
=> ["one1", "one2", "two1", "two2"]
```

Comment: Good one. I am late to post. Due to fill the CAPTCHA of SO `Are you Robot` :(